# Why does jslint say my variable is out of scope?

Tags: javascript, jslint

Why does jslint say that id_interval is out of scope?  JavaScript is function scoped last time I checked.

```
Pub.elementLoaded = function (id, callback) {
    var isLoaded = document.getElementById(id);
    var id_interval = setInterval( function() {
        if (isLoaded) {
            callback();
            clearInterval(id_interval);
        }
    }, 1);
};
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but pick a single naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

JSLint enforces what its author considers best practices, not the actual JavaScript syntactic rules. Quoting from [jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com/help.html) about variable declarations:

> JSLint uses the intersection of the var rules and the let rules, and
>   by doing so avoids the errors related to either. A name should be
>   declared only once in a function. It should be declared before it is
>   used.

In your code, `id_interval` is used inside its own declaration, at which point it strictly isn't declared yet.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer for others like me who arrive here with the same question: as @GertG explains, JSLint just wants you to declare the variable before the block in which you use it.

You have to add `var id_interval;` before you use the `setInterval()`, and then remove `var` on the following line, because now you've already declared it:

```
Pub.elementLoaded = function (id, callback) {
    var isLoaded = document.getElementById(id);
    var id_interval;
    id_interval = setInterval( function() {
        if (isLoaded) {
            callback();
            clearInterval(id_interval);
        }
    }, 1);
};
```